# HTML Form Upload PDF with other form contents using PHP

Tags: php

I have a HTML form with fields such as name, address, notes, etc.  I also have a field to upload a PDF.  The uploaded PDF get's stored on the file system.

How can I accomplish this if possibly the PDF files are larger than 2 MBs?  Also, for some reason, the uploading of the PDF (< 2 MBs) works fine in Chrome, but not in IE.  In IE, the upload doesn't even begin, but in Chrome, it completes fine.

Form header looks like:

```
method='post' ENCTYPE='multipart/formdata'
```

edit: the ini setting didn't help

The HTML

```
<input type='text' name='user' />
<input type='file' name='userfile' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to the top of your script:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '5M');
```

If that doesn't work, you can try changing that setting in php.ini

If none of this is applicable to your problem, include more of your code.

Also, change:

`multipart/formdata`

to:

```
multipart/form-data
```

If the problem persists, inspect the $_FILES array (print_r($_FILES))

Comment: What happened when you tried to modify upload_max_filesize? I also added to my answer.

Comment: Don't forget the webserver's own POST limits (ie: Apache's 'LimitRequestBody'). PHP may have been set wide open for upload limits, but Apache/IIS/whatever could still be killing the transfer.